# !PHP помощь с методом SOLID

Tags: php

Какие методы SOLID были нарушены в этом коде или что можно изменить (упростить).
Хотелось бы услышать ваши замечания и предложения (если у вас есть время).

```
interface VideoPlayerInterface
{
    public function play();
    public function rewind($seconds);
    public function playRadio();
    public function getFileInfo();
    public function ejectCD();
}

class VideoPlayer implements VideoPlayerInterface
{
    public $file;

    public function __construct()
    {
    }

    public function getVideo($file)
    {
        $this->file = $file;
    }

    public function play()
    {
        if (Auth::check()) {
            $dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database;charset=utf-8";
            $pdo = new PDO($dsn, 'root', '');
            $statement = $pdo->query("UPDATE videos SET playCount = playCount + 1 WHERE filename = ". $this->file);
            $statement->execute();

            $this->log();
        }

        // here is some code for play the video
    }

    public function rewind($seconds)
    {
        if (Auth::check()) {
            if ($seconds > 10) {
                if ($this->rewindFast($seconds)) {
                    return true;
                }
            } else {
                // here is some code for rewind video
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    public function rewindFast($seconds)
    {
        if (Auth::check()) {
            // here is some code for rewind video fast
            return true;
        }
    }

    public function log()
    {
        $logger = new TextLogger->log('Video was played');
    }

    public function playRadio()
    {
        return 'Oops! I cannot play radio';
    }

    public function getFileInfo()
    {
        return realpath($this->file);
    }

    public function ejectCD()
    {
        throw new \Exception('Oops! I cannot eject CD');
    }

}

class AviVideoPlayer extends VideoPlayer
{
    public function play()
    {
        if (pathinfo($this->file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION) !== 'avi') {
            throw new Exception;
        }

        parent::play();
    }

    public function getFileInfo()
    {
        return ['fileInfo' => pathinfo($this->file)];
    }
}

$aviPlayer = new AviVideoPlayer();
$aviPlayer->getVideo('Game_of_thrones.avi');
$aviPlayer->play();
```

Comment: Тут нарушен принцип S - single responsibility (единственной ответственности)

Comment: single responsibility видео плеер почему-то знает об какой то авторизации Auth::check(), видео плеер есть метод для запуска еще и РАДИО, хотя это ВИДЕОплеер. `getVideo` на самом деле `setVideo`

Comment: `open-closed` file public а должен быть potected

Comment: метод Auth::check не нарушает принцип единственной ответственности

Comment: 1. Принцип единственной ответственности. 2. Принцип открытости/закрытости. 3. Принцип инверсии зависимостей | Нарушены

Comment: @madfan41k  не метод, а его вызов в контексте другого класса как раз и нарушает

Comment: то-есть все классы с которых вызываются статические методы других классов нарушают принцип единственной ответственности ? ))))

Comment: @madfan41k Не все, а конкретно `VideoPlayer`. VideoPlayer - это класс который работает только в рамках плеера. `play`, `stop`, `rewind`. Он не должен знать ни о БД, ни проверять авторизацию. Это не его дело. singe responsibility гласит: " объект должен иметь одну ответственность и эта ответственность должна быть полностью инкапсулирована в класс". А VideoPlayer в данном контексте ответсвенен и за проверку авторизации, и БД подключает. Он включает так называемые  [завистливые](https://refactoring.guru/ru/smells/feature-envy) функции, которые нарушают букву `S`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Принцип единственной ответственности.

Метод play у вас отвечает за 1) установление соединения с БД 2) выполнение запроса 3) логирование 4) проверку авторизации

Остальное не по SOLID, а в целом про странности и косяки

2. Именование

Метод `getVideo`, судя по имени, должен возвращать видео, а по факту представляет из себя классический сеттер

3. Сокрытие реализации

Почему $file у вас публичный? Если нужно, то зачем отдельный сеттер (`getVideo`)

4. PDO

Вот это ОЧЕНЬ ПЛОХАЯ ПРАКТИКА

```
$pdo->query("UPDATE videos SET playCount = playCount + 1 WHERE filename = ". $this->file);
```

Всегда используйте [подготовленные запросы](http://php.net/manual/ru/pdo.prepared-statements.php) там где у вас нет железобетонной уверенности в корректности подставляемого параметра.

5. Почему все методы публичные? Как минимум `log` точно должен быть приватным(или защищенным)
6. Почему `playRadio` возвращает текстовую ошибку, а `ejectCD` бросает исключение с практически аналогичным текстом?